# Possibility to create and delete databricks resources via Azure CLI deployments

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-rm-template

Normally when you create resources using ARM templates and the azure CLI you can create using:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group $resourceGroupName --template-file "infra/template.json" --parameters "infra/parameters.json"
```

Then when I want to delete the resources I can:

```
az group delete --name $resourceGroupName
```

However, with **Databricks** this will create other resource groups as well. Even if you delete the DB resource group, you've still got these other lingering resource groups. I'd like to be able to delete the databricks **AND** all of the other resources that were created, without having to do extra manual steps.

Any idea of a clean way to do this?

Comment: when you remove workspace, managed resource group is also deleted

Comment: If you do it manually in the GUI. But nobody got time for that. If you delete it using the method above you still have the resources. What I want is a way to kill it all from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The managed resource group created by Databricks ***cannot be deleted manually since it was created by the Databricks resource itself***. The deny assignment prevents deletion of the managed resource group.

One way to remove resource is to delete the existing workspace following is the example using azure cli

**Through AZURE CLI**

I have created resource group tvs and databricks tvs for the demo purpose

***Delete resource***

Use following command in AzureCLI to delete a resource.

*Azure CLICopy*

```
az resource delete \
--resource-group tvs\
--name  tvs\
--ids  *****\
```

> (NOTE : ids is the id of the resource that can be picked from JSON view)

Before deletion

[image]

[image]

After deletion

[image]

***Delete resource group***

Use following command in AzureCLI to delete the resource group.

*Azure CLICopy*

```
az group delete --name tvs
```

[image]

Azure doesn’t currently provide a way to ***delete multiple resource groups*** at the same time.

Here’s a method that works for me.

1. Open Azure Portal
2. Click on Resource Groups
3. Select the Resource Groups that you want to delete
4. Click “Assign tags”

[image]

5. Assign a new tag called “disposable-service”(can be named anything)  and  tag value to be true

[image]

6. Open Azure Cloud Shell [https://shell.azure.com](https://shell.azure.com/) or click on the Azure Shell icon in the Azure Portal toolbar.
7. the following script into Cloud Shell and hit enter.

az group list --tag disposable-service=true --query "[].[id]" --output tsv

[image]